# Preventing a cell from being changed if a condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm a DB dev, haven't done a great deal of dev in VBA.
My thought process is, can I have a constraint in Excel... don't know.

Scenario:
I have two tabs in Microsoft Excel, the first tab contains a list of Payments made into a bank account I have, with associated records, like a value, when it was deposited, etc. Each row has an identifier I have assigned to it.

The second tab has a list of bills that come in, I assign each bill to a payment via the identifier.

What I would like to do is lock the identifier and (ideally but not a must) a few other cells in the same row, if there is a row in the second tab that shares an identifier from the first tab.

Comment: Could you share the screenshots and sample data (using the [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#)) of your tabs, the columns that need to be locked, and your code so far?

Comment: In general it is possible by setting the Locked property of the cell programatically, and then protect the sheet.

Comment: @Super Symmetry You have declared `lockCells` as `Private` so `Worksheet_Change` can't find it. Is that why you deleted your post?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Data Validation - there is an explanation of how on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VudPtXCf2bU)
Essentially you need an extra column (can be hidden) with a formula that does a `MATCH` to your other sheet and sets up a "flag" e.g.

```
=IF(IFNA(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),0) > 0, 1,0)
```

Then using Data, Data Validation set up a Custom rule that refers to the other column e.g. = B2 = 0. You can add appropriate wording to a message.